# Mat icon custom svg icons - is sanitizing safe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, security, angular-material

I wanted to add possibility to add custom svgs in mat-icon in angular 2+ application.

In order to do that one must add custom svg to mat registry and sanitize the resource url - example below

```
constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
 
     this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('hello', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/hello.svg'))
```

I'm thinking if this approach is fine for commercial apps , is sanitizing posing a threat of cross scripting or any other security issue?

IMO there is no issue here, because noone can replace the assets if they do not have access to server, right?